# Oversampling to Create Correlated Feature from Existing Feature

Tags: correlation, oversampling

For demo purposes in Python, I would like to create an array or pandas df column that shares a high degree of correlation with an existing array.

This is not as easy as it sounds and I don't think it can just be implemented with the numpy multivariate normal method because that creates two arrays from scratch following arbitrary distribution parameters.

I am not finding an answer to this so I am wondering, would it be a good idea to oversample the existing array and multiply the results by a normally distributed random integer?